# jQuery only slide 1st div in IE7 / IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, slide

i want to build a simple div slider with jQuery (example at http://jsfiddle.net/cM5fX/). All works fine in non-ie browsers and ie9. In IE7 and IE8 only the 1st div would be slide, the 2nd one stuck. Whats the problem here?

Greets
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are animating the div which id is "first", it is only apply to it, and other are not repositioning according to first (ie IE 7).

so you can apply animate on $('#slideWrapper') instead of $('#first')